# How to link one specific blade.php file to one specific css file

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I am making a project where I have used html, CSS and in the back end, I am using PHP.
the point I am stuck at is when I am connecting my front end to back end, a lot of the CSS code is
concatenating for example, I am using a class active, somewhere in another page if that class is present, it is updating the design of that page too and vice versa.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('public/assets/front')}}/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('public/assets/front')}}/css/about.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('public/assets/front')}}/css/contact.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('public/assets/front')}}/css/visas.css"/>
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('public/assets/front')}}/css/services.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('public/assets/front')}}/css/utilities.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('public/assets/front')}}/css/travel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('public/assets/front')}}/css/visas.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('public/assets/front')}}/css/countries.css" />
```

below, I have shared my code for reference.
this is how I am importing my css files

I tried to make a website where I could separate the CSS classes just in order to make it a bit more easy to edit anything in future.

Comment: Well, you could just put the `<link` tag only in the blade file you want to use it in.

Comment: if you have 2 time .active classe on the css with different styles, it will overwrite the css to the last one encountered. You can put a parent classe to prevent that overwrite (see more css hierarchy).